# check the name of an object literal property

Tags: javascript, key, object-literal

I have a shorthand function for element creation that takes a tag name and an object literal.

```
//create element
function $make(tag, parameters) {
    var o = document.createElement(t);
    if (p.style) o.style.cssText = p.style;
    if (p.class) o.className = p.class;
    if (p.text) o.textContent = p.text;
    return o;
}
```

You call it simply enough:

```
var e = $make('div', {style: 'float: left', class: 'myClass', text: 'Some Text'});
```

Instead of setting a check for each individual attribute, I'd like to set attributes using a key character prefix in the property. For instance, if I wanted to set `href` for a link, I might call:

```
var e = $make('a', {style: 'float: left', text: 'Google', ~href: 'https://www.google.com'});
```

How can I iterate through the properties of an object literal and check whether the name of the property itself (**not** the value) starts with a specific character or string? Is this even possible? If not, what would you recommend as an alternative?

Comment: Note that your function just takes an *object*. The object may have been defined using *object literal syntax* (`{ ... }`), or it may have been defined some other way (e.g., `new Object()`, or it may be some type of `Object`). "Literal" refers to how the object is lexically specified in code; it has no relevance to the object after it is created.

Comment: @apsillers While that's true in this case, that's not always true with other literals in JS; example: (`"my string" instanceof String === false`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of for...in I'd suggest using a forEach loop over the Object.keys function. This is because for ... in looks up the prototype chain (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Iterating_over_own_properties_only).

```
var obj = {"style": 'float: left', "text": 'Google', "~href": 'https://www.google.com'};
Object.keys(obj).forEach((elm) => {
  console.log("Key=>Value : " + elm + "=>" + obj[elm]);
  if(elm.contains("~")) {
    console.log("Key: " + elm + " contains ~");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! And how would I call the value of the current key to assign it to the object attribute? Is it just `key.value`?

Comment: Updated the answer to show how you could access the object property inside the forEach loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for...in` loop to get each key in the `Object`, and then check for the existence of the string or character.

In the example below, I am checking to see that the key starts with the "~" character.

```
for (const key in myObject) {
    if (key.indexOf('~') === 0) {
        // key contains '~' character
    }
}
```

you could also use regex to match a string, instead of using `indexOf`